# Survival Analysis $E[1/h(T)]=E[T]$

Tags: survival, mean, hazard

I am trying to prove that $E[1/h(T)]=E[T]$, where $h(T)$ is the hazard function.
Any idea?
Thank you.

Comment: Where did you get stuck in (dis)proving the relation? Please show your attempts.

Comment: I know that E(T) is the integrate of survival function , and the reverse hazard is S(T)/f(T) , but I don't know how to calculate  the mean of S(T)/f(T).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track.  The next step is to use the definition of expectation:
\begin{align}
E[h(T)^{-1}] = \int_0^\infty h(t)^{-1}f(t)dt = \int_0^\infty \frac{S(t)}{f(t)}f(t)dt
= \int_0^\infty S(t)dt. 
\end{align}

On the other hand, it is [well known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64186/intuition-behind-using-complementary-cdf-to-compute-expectation-for-nonnegative?noredirect=1&lq=1) that $E[T] = \int_0^\infty S(t)dt$, hence the equality.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!!